# Why does "liquid metal" do this?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I just watched [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AOgGEHoSeik) where a guy uses magnetic "liquid metal" along with a standard magnet to create some pretty cool spiky shapes. The magnetized liquid, when brought near the standard magnet, makes a bunch of small spikes.

> Why does this happen?

Comment: Look up ferrofluids.

Comment: i am assuming that you are talking about ferrofluid. ferrofluid consists of a ferric material suspended in an organic solvent. for more specific details you may wish to visit the chem SE

Comment: The effect is called [normal field instability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrofluid#Normal-field_instability). For a ferrofluid in a magnetic field the surface of least energy is not smooth, hence the spiky appearance when the neodymium magnet is brought near. I have to confess I don't know how to calculate the surface of least energy, though I suspect it is hard.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'd be tempted to use a relaxation iterative technique rather than trying for the analytic solution.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2394/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149414/2451 and links therein.